# Unable to post threads & permissions - Liferay Message Board

Tags: portlet, liferay-6

As we know we have Message-board portlet in liferay,I am facing some issues regarding Message-board portlet.

I have logged in as Admin, then also I am not able to "Post new Thread".

When I click on it just page gets refreshed.

Also same thing happens with, "Add Category" and "Permissions"

I am  getting this error logs whenever I click on cancel button through control panel

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-693][render_portlet_jsp:154] com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException: /group/control_panel/manage?p_auth=G7vEPRM8&p_p_id=162&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&doAsGroupId=10179&refererPlid=10563&_162_struts_action=%2Fmessage_boards_admin%2Fedit_message
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor.process(PortletRequestProcessor.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet.processAction(StrutsPortlet.java:212)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:548)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:579)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:294)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:944)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:688)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:560)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:537)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
```

I tried through control panel also, but it doesn't work from there as well.

But, when I click on "Unlock" in control panel, it allows me to post a new thread ONLY ONCE

I am using liferay 6.1.1 ga2 community version.

Can somebody please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your portal-ext.properties with property mentioned in below link

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/16913681